# How to make a tensorflow GAN model that attack an OCR model

Tags: python, c++, security, machine-learning, tensorflow

I was using the the attacks algorithm in the [Cleverhans](https://github.com/tensorflow/cleverhans/tree/master/examples/nips17_adversarial_competition/sample_attacks) to do an OCR attacks. Basically, I am attacking a *black-box mobile phone app* that recognize the ID numbers from picture.

I found C++ tesseract model capable of doing this. So I was planning on a transfer attacks towards the tesseract model. The accuracy of tesseract model is quite low: 100 out of 157 images.

**So my first question is that could you give me some suggestions of such OCR model that I can use directly, better if pre-trained**

- OCR model only need to recognize digits 0-9 and character X
- I am able to get some confidence values

So currently I am developing the algorithm upon tesseract model. Since the tesseract api is written in c++, I have to write the prediction model as c++ file and compile it to binary file.

*My solution of transferring images and predictions between Python and C++ is that:*

- I will first save the perturbed image locally
- run the binary file to store output labels and confidence value in a .csv file
- Python will then read the labels and confidence values from .csv file

The current problem I encountered is that Tensorflow does not consider the values after a **sess.run()** as part of the graph. So every time the code ran

```
grad = tf.gradient(y, x)
```

it says that the **grad** is None.

Below is my code of saving the image and then return the confidence values.

```
filenames = []
# save for tesseract api to use
for idx in range(images.get_shape()[0] ):
    if not os.isdir(MODEL_BUFFER):
        os.mkdir(MODEL_BUFFER)

    filename = os.path.join(MODEL_BUFFER, "temp_image_" + idx + ".JPG")
    filenames.append(filename )

    with tf.gfile.Open(os.path.join(MODEL_BUFFER, "temp_image_" + idx + ".JPG"), 'w') as f:
        img = (((images[idx, :, :, :] + 1.0) * 0.5) * 255.0)

        enc = tf.image.encode_jpeg(img)

        fname = tf.constant(filename)

        fwrite = tf.write_file(fname, enc)

        sess.run(fwrite)
# call tesseract
cmd = ["./ts_at"] + filenames
subprocess(cmd)

# read the predictions
y_preds = []
with open("output.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header_row = next(reader)
    filename = header_row.index("filename")
    confidence = header_row.index("confidence")
    ID = header_row.index("ID")
    idx = 0
    for row in reader:

        y_preds.append(int(row[confidence]) )

return y_preds
```

Also, I have tried returning tf.constant(y_preds) but still no luck. One explanation online is that Tensorflow thinks that there is no connections between the confidence values and the input images.

**So my second question is that how to solve this problem?**

Thanks